# How to check why my Heroku application cannot reach remote host?

Tags: heroku, timeout, ktor

I have deployed heroku application - Ktor server that was working for 2 years and everything was working perfect. Since few days my application cannot access host (https://api.um.warszawa.pl/). It's getting timeout error all the time. API is accessible from my local machine. How can I check who blocked the access and why? Where can I ask for enabling the access again? Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you contact whoever runs that site. [We can't answer customer service-related questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577).

Comment: Ok, but it might be that heroku has blocked that API for some reason, am I right?

Comment: It's unlikely that Heroku did anything, but if they did you need to ask _them_. As I mentioned, customer service questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I mean - is there any way that I could from console (ex. heroku's) check on which side the issue is

Comment: You can try Heroku Exec https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. I have had contacted the API team at Warsaw Town Hall - they have told me that City's Centre of Network and Data could set location restrictions on the API due to CHARLIE-CRP alarm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).